# Joining db table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

I have 2 db tables:

- courses

  ```
  id|name|teacher_id
  ```
- teachers

  ```
  id|first_name|last_name|email
  ```

I want to show `id, name` from `courses` table and `first_name, last_name` from `teachers` table.

I used `full join method`:

```
select name, 
    first_name, 
    last_name 
from courses 
full join teachers on teachers.id = courses.teacher_id;
```

And I'm getting the error below :

> Unknown column 'courses.teachers_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Try `teacher_id` instead of `teachers_id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select name, first_name, last_name from courses 
inner  join 
teachers on teachers.id = courses.teacher_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have FULL JOINS on MySQL, but achieve this as below:

In case you intend to do **FULL OUTER JOIN**:

```
select name, first_name, last_name from courses left join teachers on teachers.id = courses.teacher_id;
union all
select name, first_name, last_name from courses right join teachers on teachers.id = courses.teacher_id;
```

For **INNER JOIN**

```
select name, first_name, last_name from courses left join teachers on teachers.id = courses.teacher_id;
```